# how to update entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I update the entity using the command 
    "bin/console doctine:mapping:import --force ApiBundle xml", 
it throw error 
    Property "iduser" in "User2fa" was already declared, but it must be declared only once

Comment: Can you show us the User2fa table structure?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to add already existing field

Comment: tried from my local  database(local sever) its working fine but if I try from another database (development server) got the above error